# I am getting a blank screen on my pdo login

Tags: php, database, authentication, pdo

here's some code i did. I am trying to login to a  certain page if my  username/password are both correct - but I keep on getting a blank white page even if the username/password are either CORRECT or WRONG! I have 3 main files that I did. Home.php, enter.php, and connection.php.

Here's the code for Home.php:

```
    <?php
session_start();
?>

<html>
<h1 align="center">Welcome To Home Page</h1>
<form method="POST">
<table border="0" align="center">

<tr>

<td>

<?php
echo $_SESSION["firstname"]; 
if($_SESSION["firstname"]==null)
{
?>
    <a href="enter.php">Login</a>
    <a href="registration.php">Registration</a>
    <a href="enter.php">Logout</a>
<?php
}
else
{
?>
<a href="enter.php">Logout</a>
<?php
}
?>
</td>

</tr>

<tr>
<td>
<img src="pix.jpg" width="500" length="500"/>
</td>

</table>
</form>
</html>
```

Here's the code for Enter.php:

```
    <html>

    <form action="connection.php" method="POST">
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                Email: 
                                <input type="text" maxlength="30" name="emails" />
                            </li>

                            <li>
                                Password : 
                                <input type="password" maxlength="30" name="passwords" />
                            </li>
                            <input type="submit" maxlength="30" name="logins" value="Login" />

                        </ul>
                    </form>
    </html>
```

Here's the code for Connection.php:

```
    <?php
function getConnection(){
$db =  new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=demodatabase", "root","********");
$db ->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPION);
return $db;

$db = getConnection();
$stmt = $db->prepare("
    SELECT * FROM subscriber WHERE Email_id = :emails AND Password = :passwords
");
$stmt->bindParam(":emails"   , $users    );
$stmt->bindParam(":passwords", $passwords);
$stmt->execute();
$total = $db->rowCount();
$count = $stmt->rowCount(); 
    if ($count > 0) { 
    session_start(); 
    $_SESSION['firstname'] = 'yes'; 
    header('location: home.php'); 
    exit; 
    } 
}
?>
```

So why do I keep getting blank pages?

Comment: white screen of death = error checking\display are off

Comment: You can't call `session_start()` or `header()` once you've output anything to the browser, unless I'm mistaken from your example code - it looks like you are

Comment: Check you server logs, they will have the errors.

Comment: I don't think `function getConnection(){` has a closing brace

Comment: **Never** store passwords in plain text. @BartFriederichs That helps. Now the password is only one click further away.

Comment: turn ON error checking\dispaly

Comment: how should i turn it on Dagon?

Comment: so how would i fix it then?

Comment: at the top of the script file add `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: mysql logs onxampp? which logs u talking about Bart?

Comment: Server logs, they probably are in `/var/log` on your local machine. And use @name to call someone.

Comment: i did that Dagon...but I don't get any errors displayed!

Comment: @Dagon...that doesn't work!

Comment: @Marcel Korpel...are these the Xampp logs?

Comment: Yes, the Apache logs.

Comment: @Marcel...lemme see...there are access, error,and php_error logs, which ones?

Comment: @Marcel...which log do I check? the php_error log has absolutely NOTHING on the files that I'm doing!

Comment: Then check the other log files.

Comment: I did Macel...and I get NO ERRORS WHATSOEVER!!!

Answer (score 1):

Look at your code:

```
    <?php
function getConnection(){
    // …
}
?>
```

You have everything in *one* function and never call that. You need a closing curly brace here:

```
function getConnection(){
    $db =  new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=demodatabase", "root","********");
    $db ->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPION);
    return $db;
}  // here

$db = getConnection();
```

Properly indenting your code would have helped.

On a side note, it's clear that you are storing passwords in plain text. **Never do that!** Use a [good password hashing algorithm](http://php.net/password) to hash passwords!

Also, using `session_start` or `header` after something has been sent to the browser is useless. Watch the unwanted spaces before `<?php`.

Comment: what do I do now? I got the following error: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'demodatabase.subscriber' doesn't exist' in C:\xampp\htdocs\Registra2\connection.php:13 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\Registra2\connection.php(13): PDOStatement->execute() #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\Registra2\connection.php on line 13

Comment: why did i get that error above - lemme repeat it again - Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'demodatabase.subscriber' doesn't exist' in C:\xampp\htdocs\Registra2\connection.php:13 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\Registra2\connection.php(13): PDOStatement->execute() #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\Registra2\connection.php on line 13

Comment: @user3047348 It's just what it says: your table `subscriber` doesn't exist. You'll have to create it before you can retrieve records from it.

Comment: i fixed that - had the table but under a different name - now this is what i get - 
Fatal error: Call to undefined method PDO::rowCount() in C:\xampp\htdocs\Registra2\connection.php on line 14

Comment: how do i define rowcount() now?

Comment: @user3047348 Read the error message more carefully, it just says what the issue is. Why did you write `$total = $db->rowCount()`? That will not work, as [`rowCount` is a method of `PDOStatement`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php).